# export doesn't work in shell script but does via CLI

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I have the following file - test.sh - in .:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ASDF=test
```

I do `chmod +x test.sh`,then `./test.sh` and finally `echo $ASDF` and...  nothing. It's as though $ASDF hasn't been set. But if I do it via the CLI instead of a shell script it works just fine and $ASDF is defined.

Why isn't the shell script working?

Comment: cross site duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip#176788

Answer (score 9):

It is because:

```
./test.sh
```

will create a sub shell and set env variables in the sub shell. Once sub shell exits this variable isn't available in parent shell.

Use this form to avoid forking a sub shell and execute `test.sh` in the current shell itself:

```
. ./test.sh
```

OR:

```
source ./test.sh
```

Now that variable `ASDF` will be available in current shell also.